# Divergence of $\zeta(z)$ tamed or not tamed by any analytic continuation

Tags: sequences-and-series, complex-analysis, number-theory, riemann-zeta, analytic-continuation

We know the conjecture about the Riemann hypothesis is about the nontrivial zeros are on
$$(1/2 + r i)$$
for some $r \in \mathbb{R}$ of Riemann zeta function.

My question is how many divergences of $\zeta(z)$ can be tamed by analytic continuations and how many divergences of $\zeta(z)$ canNOT be tamed by analytic continuations?

For example,
$$\zeta(1)=1+2+3+4+\dots=\infty$$
seem not to be tamed by any analytic continuation. How about other $\zeta(z)$? Are there others cannot be done by analytic continuation as a finite value?

Comment: I am not quite sure what "tamed by analytic continuations" means, but your "untamed" example actually [zeta regularizes](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Zeta_function_regularization) to $-1/12$. My guess is that the only "untamed" sums happen at poles, and for zeta that would be only the harmonic series at $z=1$.

Comment: I think you mean the Harmonic series $\zeta(1)=1+\frac{1}{2}+\frac{1}{3}+\cdots$ is not "tamed by analytic continuation" (although Ramanujan summation gives it the value of $\gamma$, the Euler-Mascheroni constant).

Comment: Just to add on to this, the zeta function near $s=1$ looks like $\zeta(s)=\frac{1}{s-1}+\gamma+o(1)$ as $s\to 1$. Hence you can regularize it to $\gamma$. In fact, it is common to regularize such a divergence by subtracting it off and looking at the constant term in the asymptotic expansion.

Answer (score 1):

The only pole of the Riemann zeta function is at $ z = 1 $, so that's the only divergence that's not "tamed" by analytic continuation.

Comment: Yes I expected that should be -- how should we show this? +1 thanks

Comment: @anniemarieheart You can find the analytic continuation of the Riemann zeta function to the region $ z > 0 $ at https://proofwiki.org/wiki/Integral_Representation_of_Riemann_Zeta_Function_in_terms_of_Fractional_Part, and you can deal with the region $ z \leq 0 $ using the functional equation for the Riemann zeta function.

Comment: @anniemarieheart Also, Conifold is right in the comments: the sum you give in your question would be regularized into $ \zeta(-1) = -1/12 $.

Answer (score 1):

The series $\sum_{n\ge 1}n^{-s}$ diverges whenever $\Re(s)\le 1$,

Iff $s=1$ or $\Re(s)<1$ then $\lim_{N\to \infty}|\sum_{n\ge N}n^{-s}|= \infty$.

For $\Re(s)\le 1$,$s\not\in \Bbb{R}$ then $\frac{\sum_{n\ge N}n^{-s}}{|\sum_{n\ge N}n^{-s}|}$ oscillates.

For $\Re(s)\le 1,s\ne 1$
$$\lim_{N\to \infty} \frac{\sum_{n\ge N}n^{-s}}{\int_1^N x^{-s}dx}=\lim_{N\to \infty} \frac{1-s}{N^{1-s}}\sum_{n\ge N}n^{-s}=1$$

It is mostly similar for $\eta(s)$ with $\Re(s)=0$ instead of $\Re(s)=1$.

For the analytic continuation: you really have to compare with $\frac1{1-s}$ which is the analytic continuation of $\sum_{n\ge 0} s^n,|s|<1$ to $\Bbb{C}-\{1\}$, the setting is exactly the same for $\zeta(s)$.

Next, consider the functional equation saying that $\pi^{-(1/2+s)/2}\Gamma((1/2+s)/2)\zeta(1/2+s)$ is an even function which is real-valued for $s$ on the imaginary axis, thus having a zero at each sign change (the non-trivial zeros, under the RH).